# Google Play Games - Application in alpha/beta test - Error 10004 at sign-in RESULT APP MISCONFIGURED

Tags: android, google-play-games, signing

**My situation :**

Google Play Games works well when I test it directly on my device (with Android Studio direct generation)
With this configuration, all the workflow is ok.

I am now in alpha/beta testing 
I generate with Android Studio a signed APK and i upload it on the Google Play Console.
My application and my Game application are both published and i am with other people in test emails.
But when i try to sign in to Google Play Games, i get the error 10004 which correspond to RESULT_APP_MISCONFIGURED.

I checked and i think all is ok :(

Could you give me ideas to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Working on two machines? debug.keystores will be different. Check my full answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31124884/3508719

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you have only linked your game with the debug key.
You should follow the (admittedly, confusing) steps to link your game with both the debug key AND your release key.
https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling#a_create_a_linked_application