# Google Play Services resultCode = 10004

Tags: android, google-play-services

I used the google demo example TypeANumber from developer.android.com/training. I configured the app correctly in the play.google.com developer console, even published it, configured as well correctly the game service TypeANumber in the developer console and linked the previous mentioned app, even published the service and I still keep getting the resultCode 10004 which stands for

> public static final int RESULT_APP_MISCONFIGURED
>   Result code sent back to the calling Activity when the game is not properly
>   configured to access the Games service. Developers should check the logs for more details.
>   Constant Value: 10004 (0x00002714)

Used code is:

```
package com.sitewalk.typeanumber;

import android.accounts.AccountManager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnCancelListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender.SendIntentException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.AccountPicker;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

import com.google.android.gms.games.Games;

public class GooglePlayServicesActivity extends Activity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final String TAG = "GooglePlayServicesActivity";
    private static final String KEY_IN_RESOLUTION = "is_in_resolution";
    private static final String DIALOG_ERROR = "dialog_error";
    private static final int REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR = 1001;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private boolean mIsInResolution;
    private boolean mResolvingError=false;
    private static final String STATE_RESOLVING_ERROR = "resolving_error";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(Games.API)
                    .addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
                            // Optionally, add additional APIs and scopes if required.
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();
        }
        mResolvingError = savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.getBoolean(STATE_RESOLVING_ERROR, false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (!mResolvingError) {  // more about this later
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBoolean(KEY_IN_RESOLUTION, mIsInResolution);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR) {
            mResolvingError = false;
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Make sure the app is not already connected or attempting to connect
                if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting() && !mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void retryConnecting() {
        mIsInResolution = false;
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connected");
        startActivityForResult(Games.Achievements.getAchievementsIntent(mGoogleApiClient), 5638676);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection suspended");
        retryConnecting();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        if (mResolvingError) {
            // Already attempting to resolve an error.
            return;
        } else if (result.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                mResolvingError = true;
                result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR);
            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                // There was an error with the resolution intent. Try again.
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        } else {
            // Show dialog using GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog()
            showErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode());
            mResolvingError = true;
        }
    }

    /* Creates a dialog for an error message */
    private void showErrorDialog(int errorCode) {
        // Create a fragment for the error dialog
        ErrorDialogFragment dialogFragment = new ErrorDialogFragment();
        // Pass the error that should be displayed
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DIALOG_ERROR, errorCode);
        dialogFragment.setArguments(args);
        dialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "errordialog");
    }

    /* Called from ErrorDialogFragment when the dialog is dismissed. */
    public void onDialogDismissed() {
        mResolvingError = false;
    }

    /* A fragment to display an error dialog */
    public static class ErrorDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
        public ErrorDialogFragment() { }

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Get the error code and retrieve the appropriate dialog
            int errorCode = this.getArguments().getInt(DIALOG_ERROR);
            return GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(errorCode,
                    this.getActivity(), REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            ((GooglePlayServicesActivity)getActivity()).onDialogDismissed();
        }
    }
}
```

as well a correct AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sitewalk.typeanumber" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".GooglePlayServicesActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
                   android:value="@string/app_id" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

with the correct APP-ID (checked digit after digit), 
and a build.gradle containing the play-services dependencies:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sitewalk.typeanumber"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
}
```

Logcat is not telling me any infos regarding the 10004 codeResult:

```
01-28 11:10:54.735  31182-31182/com.sitewalk.typeanumber D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
01-28 11:10:54.755  31182-31188/com.sitewalk.typeanumber D/dalvikvm﹕ Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
01-28 11:10:55.055  31182-31182/com.sitewalk.typeanumber I/System.out﹕ Sending WAIT chunk
01-28 11:10:55.055  31182-31182/com.sitewalk.typeanumber W/ActivityThread﹕ Application com.sitewalk.typeanumber is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
01-28 11:10:55.775  31182-31188/com.sitewalk.typeanumber I/dalvikvm﹕ Debugger is active
01-28 11:10:55.865  31182-31182/com.sitewalk.typeanumber I/System.out﹕ Debugger has connected
01-28 11:10:55.865  31182-31182/com.sitewalk.typeanumber I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
01-28 11:10:56.075  31182-31182/com.sitewalk.typeanumber I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
01-28 11:10:56.275  31182-31182/com.sitewalk.typeanumber I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
01-28 11:10:56.475  31182-31182/com.sitewalk.typeanumber I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
01-28 11:10:56.675  31182-31182/com.sitewalk.typeanumber I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
01-28 11:10:56.875  31182-31182/com.sitewalk.typeanumber I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
01-28 11:10:57.075  31182-31182/com.sitewalk.typeanumber I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
01-28 11:10:57.275  31182-31182/com.sitewalk.typeanumber I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
01-28 11:10:57.475  31182-31182/com.sitewalk.typeanumber I/System.out﹕ debugger has settled (1340)
01-28 11:10:57.755  31182-31182/com.sitewalk.typeanumber W/PopupManager﹕ You have not specified a View to use as content view for popups. Falling back to the Activity content view which may not work properly in future versions of the API. Use setViewForPopups() to set your content view.
01-28 11:10:57.835  31182-31182/com.sitewalk.typeanumber I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.07
    Build Date: 04/07/14 Mon
    Local Branch: au011
    Remote Branch:
    Local Patches:
    Reconstruct Branch:
01-28 11:10:57.865  31182-31182/com.sitewalk.typeanumber D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
01-28 11:11:01.435  31182-31182/com.sitewalk.typeanumber I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 211 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-28 11:11:01.665  31182-31182/com.sitewalk.typeanumber I/ActivityManager﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@42e3b748 time:437201118
01-28 11:11:10.835  31182-31182/com.sitewalk.typeanumber I/ActivityManager﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@42e3b748 time:437210285
```

Only one event log I have is:

```
11:10:34 Gradle build finished in 5 sec
```

Does anyone see my mistake?

Comment: Try using a different google account than the one registered with the play store for testing? I remember seeing a lot of such access issues resolved like this

Comment: Or the first answer to this:? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943237/google-play-game-services-testing-accounts-login-results-in-unknown-error/16945760#16945760

Comment: I tried with a different Google Account from my company but the same error occurs.

Comment: I didn't know that when creating the game service, you have to provide the fingerprint of the key with which you're going to sign the apk. The provided fingerprint was thus not the same than from the signing key. I have now considered this and changed this in another project, with the same 10004 error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't link the game service with the application where the debug key was set.
You have to link your service twice with your application, one time your package name with the release key fingerprint and one time your package name with the debug key fingerprint as described in
https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling#c_specify_client_id_settings

There is a similar question: 
[Google Play Games - Application in alpha/beta test - Error 10004 at sign-in RESULT APP MISCONFIGURED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25617715/google-play-games-application-in-alpha-beta-test-error-10004-at-sign-in-resu)

Comment: For the sake of completeness, make sure you also added your google user as a test user.

Answer (score 1):

Note - if you were developing on one machine and now you switched to a different one, your debug.keystore will be different, therefore you'll require a new linked app since their SHA1 are different.

Not sure if that was your case, but was the reason for my 10004.