# Android leaderboard not working after publish shows RESULT_APP_MISCONFIGURED error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play-services, leaderboard

I have added leaderboard to my application(game). It works fine while I run the application directly in my phone from Android studio . But after downloading the app from alpha testing in googleplay, the leaderboard is not working.

It shows app misconfigured error.

> RESULT_APP_MISCONFIGURED

I have added the SHA1 key in google developer console properly. I checked the SHA1 key again and found the key is right.

I searched through this topics in stackoverflow but could not find any proper solution to my problem. I also checked [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25617715/google-play-games-application-in-alpha-beta-test-error-10004-at-sign-in-resu) but it doesn't solve the problem.

Please see the below screen shots which I took from google developer console. I have erased the package name/sha1 key and other private things from the screen shots for security purpose.

1. Linked App
   [image: Linked App]
2. Leader board
   [image: Leader Board]
3. Developer console
   [image: Developer Console]

And below is the game helper class I used in my code.

```
    class GameHelperUtils {
    public static final int R_UNKNOWN_ERROR = 0;
    public static final int R_SIGN_IN_FAILED = 1;
    public static final int R_APP_MISCONFIGURED = 2;
    public static final int R_LICENSE_FAILED = 3;

    private final static String[] FALLBACK_STRINGS = {
            "*Unknown error.",
            "*Failed to sign in. Please check your network connection and try again.",
            "*The application is incorrectly configured. Check that the package name and signing certificate match the client ID created in Developer Console. Also, if the application is not yet published, check that the account you are trying to sign in with is listed as a tester account. See logs for more information.",
            "*License check failed."
    };

    private final static int[] RES_IDS = {
            R.string.gamehelper_unknown_error, R.string.gamehelper_sign_in_failed,
            R.string.gamehelper_app_misconfigured, R.string.gamehelper_license_failed
    };

    static String activityResponseCodeToString(int respCode) {
        switch (respCode) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                return "RESULT_OK";
            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                return "RESULT_CANCELED";
            case GamesActivityResultCodes.RESULT_APP_MISCONFIGURED:
                return "RESULT_APP_MISCONFIGURED";
            case GamesActivityResultCodes.RESULT_LEFT_ROOM:
                return "RESULT_LEFT_ROOM";
            case GamesActivityResultCodes.RESULT_LICENSE_FAILED:
                return "RESULT_LICENSE_FAILED";
            case GamesActivityResultCodes.RESULT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED:
                return "RESULT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED";
            case GamesActivityResultCodes.RESULT_SIGN_IN_FAILED:
                return "SIGN_IN_FAILED";
            default:
                return String.valueOf(respCode);
        }
    }

    static String errorCodeToString(int errorCode) {
        switch (errorCode) {
            case ConnectionResult.DEVELOPER_ERROR:
                return "DEVELOPER_ERROR(" + errorCode + ")";
            case ConnectionResult.INTERNAL_ERROR:
                return "INTERNAL_ERROR(" + errorCode + ")";
            case ConnectionResult.INVALID_ACCOUNT:
                return "INVALID_ACCOUNT(" + errorCode + ")";
            case ConnectionResult.LICENSE_CHECK_FAILED:
                return "LICENSE_CHECK_FAILED(" + errorCode + ")";
            case ConnectionResult.NETWORK_ERROR:
                return "NETWORK_ERROR(" + errorCode + ")";
            case ConnectionResult.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                return "RESOLUTION_REQUIRED(" + errorCode + ")";
            case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_DISABLED:
                return "SERVICE_DISABLED(" + errorCode + ")";
            case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_INVALID:
                return "SERVICE_INVALID(" + errorCode + ")";
            case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_MISSING:
                return "SERVICE_MISSING(" + errorCode + ")";
            case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED:
                return "SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED(" + errorCode + ")";
            case ConnectionResult.SIGN_IN_REQUIRED:
                return "SIGN_IN_REQUIRED(" + errorCode + ")";
            case ConnectionResult.SUCCESS:
                return "SUCCESS(" + errorCode + ")";
            default:
                return "Unknown error code " + errorCode;
        }
    }

    static void printMisconfiguredDebugInfo(Context ctx) {
        Log.w("GameHelper", "****");
        Log.w("GameHelper", "****");
        Log.w("GameHelper", "**** APP NOT CORRECTLY CONFIGURED TO USE GOOGLE PLAY GAME SERVICES");
        Log.w("GameHelper", "**** This is usually caused by one of these reasons:");
        Log.w("GameHelper", "**** (1) Your package name and certificate fingerprint do not match");
        Log.w("GameHelper", "****     the client ID you registered in Developer Console.");
        Log.w("GameHelper", "**** (2) Your App ID was incorrectly entered.");
        Log.w("GameHelper", "**** (3) Your game settings have not been published and you are ");
        Log.w("GameHelper", "****     trying to log in with an account that is not listed as");
        Log.w("GameHelper", "****     a test account.");
        Log.w("GameHelper", "****");
        if (ctx == null) {
            Log.w("GameHelper", "*** (no Context, so can't print more debug info)");
            return;
        }

        Log.w("GameHelper", "**** To help you debug, here is the information about this app");
        Log.w("GameHelper", "**** Package name         : " + ctx.getPackageName());
        Log.w("GameHelper", "**** Cert SHA1 fingerprint: " + getSHA1CertFingerprint(ctx));
        Log.w("GameHelper", "**** App ID from          : " + getAppIdFromResource(ctx));
        Log.w("GameHelper", "****");
        Log.w("GameHelper", "**** Check that the above information matches your setup in ");
        Log.w("GameHelper", "**** Developer Console. Also, check that you're logging in with the");
        Log.w("GameHelper", "**** right account (it should be listed in the Testers section if");
        Log.w("GameHelper", "**** your project is not yet published).");
        Log.w("GameHelper", "****");
        Log.w("GameHelper", "**** For more information, refer to the troubleshooting guide:");
        Log.w("GameHelper", "****   http://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting");
    }

    static String getAppIdFromResource(Context ctx) {
        try {
            Resources res = ctx.getResources();
            String pkgName = ctx.getPackageName();
            int res_id = res.getIdentifier("app_id", "string", pkgName);
            return res.getString(res_id);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return "??? (failed to retrieve APP ID)";
        }
    }

    static String getSHA1CertFingerprint(Context ctx) {
        try {
            Signature[] sigs = ctx.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    ctx.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES).signatures;
            if (sigs.length == 0) {
                return "ERROR: NO SIGNATURE.";
            } else if (sigs.length > 1) {
                return "ERROR: MULTIPLE SIGNATURES";
            }
            byte[] digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1").digest(sigs[0].toByteArray());
            StringBuilder hexString = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < digest.length; ++i) {
                if (i > 0) {
                    hexString.append(":");
                }
                byteToString(hexString, digest[i]);
            }
            return hexString.toString();

        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return "(ERROR: package not found)";
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return "(ERROR: SHA1 algorithm not found)";
        }
    }

    static void byteToString(StringBuilder sb, byte b) {
        int unsigned_byte = b < 0 ? b + 256 : b;
        int hi = unsigned_byte / 16;
        int lo = unsigned_byte % 16;
        sb.append("0123456789ABCDEF".substring(hi, hi + 1));
        sb.append("0123456789ABCDEF".substring(lo, lo + 1));
    }

    static String getString(Context ctx, int whichString) {
        whichString = whichString >= 0 && whichString < RES_IDS.length ? whichString : 0;
        int resId = RES_IDS[whichString];
        try {
            return ctx.getString(resId);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Log.w(GameHelper.TAG, "*** GameHelper could not found resource id #" + resId + ". " +
                "This probably happened because you included it as a stand-alone JAR. " +
                "BaseGameUtils should be compiled as a LIBRARY PROJECT, so that it can access " +
                "its resources. Using a fallback string.");
            return FALLBACK_STRINGS[whichString];
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me solve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Play Games - Application in alpha/beta test - Error 10004 at sign-in RESULT APP MISCONFIGURED](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25617715/google-play-games-application-in-alpha-beta-test-error-10004-at-sign-in-resu)

Comment: I already checked that solution. But unfortunately that does not solve my problem. :(

Comment: Have you also noticed [Voy's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31124884/6124253)? Or doesn't it apply to your situation?

Comment: yes I have noticed that. But no other machines are used to release the app rather than mine. And I have checked the SHA1 key again. And found nothing wrong with that key. Thanks for your suggestions. :)

Comment: Sorry. But can you provide further details? Because as I'm seeing it, other than the fact that you have checked the SHA1 (which is correct, so no changes were made) your post is a possible duplicate to the one commented above. Can you provide further details? As per [docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesActivityResultCodes#constant-summary): Result code sent back to the calling Activity when the game is not properly configured to access the Games service. **Developers should check the logs for more details.**

Comment: I have edited my question. Added code and screen shots. Please take a look above. Thank you for your supports. :)

Comment: Much better. More info for the community. Are there any logs though? Have you also seen/done what is advised in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28429065/6124253) answer before?

Comment: Sorry there are no logs, only RESULT_APP_MISCONFIGURED error. Yes I have tried the advised stated in that answer.

Comment: Have you tested this on multiple devices also?

Comment: Yes I have tested on several devices and also tested on several manufacturers(like samsung/sony/htc/motorla). but leaderboard does not work on any of the devices, if the apk downloaded from play store. All the devices works fine while running directly from android studio.

Answer (score 0):

This could be possible source of error:

> "You should create two client IDs, one with the release certificate
>   fingerprint and another with the debug certificate fingerprint. Make
>   sure to use the same package name for both. This allows Google Play
>   games services to recognize calls from your linked APKs that are
>   signed with either certificate. For more information about certificate
>   signing for Android, see Signing Your Application."

Therefore "Unpublish Your Game" in Game Services. Then "Delete Leaderboard" and after you publish your game also publish Game Service Leaderboard. Do not install the apk file on your phone before publishing your game!